# How to add a new jarfile to eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I want to add new jar file to my project in eclipse. But when I trying Java build path ==> Add external Jars it makes a new library called referenced libraries. 
So when I tried to import jfreechart1.0.1 it went to that library. So my import method is not working. 
 
 **import org.jfree.data.xy.DefaultTableXYDataset;**

 
Because jar file is not in JRE system library. Help me.

Comment: Do you want to define the jar as a library or just put the jar insoide your project and use it? If you just want to use it then create a lib folder inside your project, place the jar file there and use "Add JARs" instead of "Add External JARs" this time...

Comment: You have to do Build Path > Add external archive instead of Add Librairies

Comment: @mschenk74 when I did that "Add JARs" work they go to KeyLister folder. :(

Comment: @fluminis I done that too. Still makes a new library called referenced libraries.

Comment: @mschenk74 I want to my import recognized. So please help me.

Comment: Click the project > `Project` > `Clean...` then press ok

Comment: @Dilini here is also a youtube link explaining it: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeYGak5DeBg or another one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtzAf8tyuAM . You might need to refresh your project afterwards in some rare cases. You could also try to close your project and reopen it

Comment: guess what after cleaning its working. really thanks guys for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to the projects properties, build path, and browse to it.